# Вопрос по AngularJS. Как сделать сложную логику в темплейтах?

Tags: angularjs

Как сделать сложную логику в темплейтах?

На сколько я понимаю, что в Ангуляре такая система:

Директивы - для манипуляции с DOM элементами, 
Контролеры хранят модели, как не странно, 
Фильтры позволяют организовать логику в темплейтах.

Возможно ли сгенерировать такой код в темплейте, как пример:

```
createCalendar = function(id, year, month) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);

        var mon = month - 1; // месяцы в JS идут от 0 до 11, а не от 1 до 12
        var d = new Date(year, mon);

        var table = '<table ><tr><th>пн</th><th>вт</th><th>ср</th><th>чт</th><th>пт</th><th>сб</th><th>вс</th></tr><tr>';

        // заполнить первый ряд от понедельника
        // и до дня, с которого начинается месяц
        // * * * | 1  2  3  4
        for (var i=0; i<getDay(d); i++) {
            table += '<td></td>';
        }

        // ячейки календаря с датами
        while(d.getMonth() == mon) {
            table += '<td>'+d.getDate()+'</td>';

            if (getDay(d) % 7 == 6) { // вс, последний день - перевод строки
                table += '</tr><tr>';
            }

            d.setDate(d.getDate()+1);
        }

        // добить таблицу пустыми ячейками, если нужно
        if (getDay(d) != 0) {
            for (var i=getDay(d); i<7; i++) {
                table += '<td></td>';
            }
        }

        // закрыть таблицу
        table += '</tr></table>';

        // только одно присваивание innerHTML
        elem.innerHTML = table;
    }

    function getDay(date) { // получить номер дня недели, от 0(пн) до 6(вс)
        var day = date.getDay();
        if (day == 0) day = 7;
        return day - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так: http://jsfiddle.net/RubaXa/mPp6E/

Возможно есть способ оптимальней, но опыта мало.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Значит получается, что директивы в ангуляре существуют не только для манипуляции с DOM, но и реализации логики темплейтов.

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы вкадываете в логику темплайтов? В моем понимании логика, это if/case/for и т.п. Директивы в Ангуляре ближе к  html-компонентам.

Comment: Да, if, else. В директиве существуют контроллер. Если я хочу что бы взаимодействовали два компонента (2 директивы) между собой, у них должен быть общий контроллер, я в правильном направлении мыслю? Например, перетаскивание объектов на дни календаря или обновление всей модели при выборе дня в календаре.

Comment: обычно такое взаимодейтсвие делают либо через родительскую директиву (которая управляет дочерними компонентами) либо используют события. Если делать через родительскую директиву то angular позволяет указать контроллер родительской директивы в опции require, например `require: '^ngModel'` или `require: '^myParentDirective'`, либо можно просто передавать колбеки через атрибуты

Answer (score 1):

Советую внизу посмотреть, там тимплейты подключают, так же есть решения. На ангуляре можно генерировать по средствам директив  http://yadi.sk/d/-ucNW7obKebYa

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js